# Some General Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number and $a_j$ be a sequence of rationals
converging to $\alpha.$ Because $\{a_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of
rationals, we can express each $a_j$ as a fraction of lowest terms, i.e.
$$a_j = \frac{\delta_j}{\beta_j}.$$
I want to prove that $\beta_j$ tends to infinity, but I am having difficulty
forming the argument. Coming from the definition of convergence, I know that
for $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}. |a_j - \alpha| < \epsilon$ for
$j > N$, which implies that 
$$|\frac{\delta_j}{\beta_j} - \alpha| 
= |\frac{\delta_j - \alpha\beta_j}{\beta_j}|.$$
I know that this the absolute value of an irrational number, but I am not
completely sure how to use this in my argument. If $\beta_j$ tended to a
constant $\beta,$ I think it would be best to find an $\epsilon$ that the above
absolute value will always be bigger than. I'm just not finding the intuition
to see which $\epsilon$ that might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the $\beta_j$ do not have limit $\infty$. Then by definition there is a $B$ such that $\beta_j\le B$ for infinitely many $j$. But there are only finitely many positive integers $\le B$. So there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\beta_j=n$ for infinitely many $j$.

Consider the collection $J$ of all $j$ such that $\beta_j=n$. The sequence $\delta_{j}/n$, where $j$ ranges over $J$,  has limit $\alpha$. Since it has a limit, and the $\delta_j$ are integers, $\delta_j$ must be constant for large enough $j\in J$. Let that constant be  $m$. Then our sequence has limit $\frac{m}{n}$, contradicting the irrationality of $\alpha$.